# Nginx: location regex not working with question mark ,return 404 instead

Tags: regex, nginx

i have this URI `/orls/myservice/f?p=4550` and the following location

```
location ~ "^/(.+)/myservice/f?p=(.+)$" {
 .....
}
```

nginx is returning a 404 not found. the problem might come from the ? so i tried `\?` but i'm still getting the same error. Can anyone help ?